# Margin/padding in FrameLayout not going away

Tags: android, xml, android-framelayout

[image: Current Playbar]
I have a FrameLayout which contains a Playbar I am using that displays information about the music playing along with the toggles. For some reason, I cannot get the padding at the top of the frame layout to go away. I have tried making the margins/paddings 0dp of all the elements and the whole layout programmatically and via the XML but nothing is working. I am assuming it is just some natural behavior built into FrameLayout.  I have also tried setting the FrameLayout to the same desired height (56dp/ dimen/playbar_size) but the padding still is there.

```
<SeekBar
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/playbar_size"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/quantum_ic_skip_next_white_24"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/art"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/playbar_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/playbar_size"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Desired view, with no padding and seekbar all the way the top – this is actual height it is supposed to be.

[image: Desired view, with no padding and seekbar all the way the top – this is actual height it is supposed to be]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by doing two things.
Instead of setting the background to a color in the XML, I created a new shape object which had 0 padding all around and the color I wanted.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccentBrightOpaque"/>
<padding
    android:bottom="0dip"
    android:left="0dip"
    android:right="0dip"
    android:top="0dip"/>
</shape>
```

Then I programmatically set the background via java code to the shape resource and programmatically set the padding to 0 as well.

```
playbar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbar_background);
playbar.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe padding is because of this :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/art"
android:layout_width="@dimen/playbar_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/playbar_size"
android:layout_gravity="left|top"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
```

This image view is covering the top portion of frame layout since you have put the gravity as

```
android:layout_gravity="left|top"
```

Could you please try removing that and check?

Comment: I've tried that and it also hasn't fixed it. I tried again to make sure and it still won't work :/